# SharePoint SPTimerV4 stops automatically

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, content-management

My farm SharePoint 2010 Products and Configuration Wizard fails
with the log err message 
 "The exclusive inplace upgrader timer job failed" 
SPTimerV4 is running as farm administrator with necessary sql permissions.
When this error happens SPTimerV4 stops automatically.

Event log message is as follows

Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Also I notice when deploying .wsp solutions with STSADM status is stuck with "deploying"
and never finishes. Why the timer job stops frequently?

Comment: Please, check if the current user (that you use to runs SharePoint Wizard) contains these roles in SQL Server: DB_CREATOR and SECURITY_ADMIN and the same user needs to be a DB_OWNER into `SharePoint_Config` and `SharePoint_Admin_....` Databases

Answer (score 0):

Check if "domain user has 'log on as service' permissions"?

When ever 'Recycle Timer Service' restarts (on a scheduled basis), it restarts "SPTomerV4" service also which with the above permission disabled fails to restart.

Ref: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/1cf30506-4cf6-4d6c-a56d-565a83668c1e

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424%28WS.10%29.aspx?ppud=4